# python3.8 multiprocess Lock

Tags: multiprocessing, locking, python-3.8

this is my python3.8 code on MacOS, but it throws FileNotFoundError. And it's ok on python3.6 or python3.7. Very Strange!!!

```
# coding: utf-8
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock


def task(name, lock):
    lock.acquire()
    print('%s 1' % name)
    time.sleep(1)
    print('%s 2' % name)
    lock.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mutex = Lock()
    for i in range(3):
        p = Process(target=task, args=('Process %s' % i, mutex))
        p.start()
```

And the result

```
......

"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 110, in __setstate__
    self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock._rebuild(*state)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a join in there.  Note, there is no guarantee the processes will start in numerical order as you require.  you would need to add a delay in before the process start to ensure it was added to the execution queue in the order you expect.

```
# coding: utf-8
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock


def task(name, lock):
    lock.acquire()
    print('%s 1' % name)
    time.sleep(1)
    print('%s 2' % name)
    lock.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    proceses = []
    mutex = Lock()
    for i in range(3):
        p = Process(target=task, args=('Process %s' % i, mutex))
        proceses.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in proceses:
        p.join()
```